# Can an htpasswd apply to all URLs except one?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I have an htaccess setup for my domain, but I want one specific URL to not have htpasswd protection.  That URL is a rewritten URL and doesn't have an actual directory associated with it.

Is there a way to use the root htaccess to htpasswd protect the entire site except for that one specific URL?

**Edit (my code, including Jon Lin's suggestion, which isn't working for me):**

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =subdomain.example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/messenger/parse" NOPASSWD=true
AuthUserFile /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxxxxx/subdomain.example.com/.htpasswd
AuthName "Staging Server"
AuthType Basic
Order Deny,Allow
Satisfy any
Deny from all
Require valid-user
Allow from env=NOPASSWD
```

Answer (score 3):

You can setup something like `SetEnvIf` to set an environment variable for a given Request URI. Then in the auth definition, you can use the `Satisfy Any` and `Allow from env` directives to tell apache that access can be granted either by authentication or if the environment variable exists (which is only set for a specific URI). Example:

```
# set the NOPASSWD variable if the request is for a specific URI
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/specific/uri/nopasswd/$" NOPASSWD=true

# Auth directives
AuthUserFile /var/www/htpasswd
AuthName "Password Protected"
AuthType Basic
Order Deny,Allow
# Any requirment satisfies
Satisfy any
# Deny all requests
Deny from all
# except if user is authenticated
Require valid-user
# or if NOPASSWD is set
Allow from env=NOPASSWD
```

Comment: Thanks!  This makes sense to me and I just tried implementing it, but the htpasswd login box is still appearing when I go to the URL intended to not be protected.  I edited my original question above with my code (including my implementation of your suggestion).

Comment: Try putting that before you rewrite the URI, if everything gets rewritten to `/index.php/`, then the `SetEnvIf` isn't going to match.